# Failed to compile with distcc, but OK without it

Tags: c, compilation

I'm trying to compile RaLink drivers for usb wifi dongle. Without using distcc everything is OK but if i use distcc there is error.
Here make log:

```
make -C UTIL/
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6.util /home/tobi/RaLink_driver/UTIL/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /home/tobi/linux/ SUBDIRS=/home/tobi/RaLink_driver/UTIL/os/linux modules
mkdir -p /home/tobi/RaLink_driver/UTIL/os/linux/.tmp_versions
rm -f /home/tobi/RaLink_driver/UTIL/os/linux/.tmp_versions/*
make -f scripts/Makefile.build obj=/home/tobi/RaLink_driver/UTIL/os/linux
  mipsel-linux-gcc -Wp,-MD,/home/tobi/RaLink_driver/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/.rt_linux.o.d  -nostdinc  -Iinclude  -include include/linux/autoconf.h -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -O2  -mabi=32 -G 0 -mno-abicalls -fno-pic -pipe -msoft-float -ffreestanding --trap -Wno-uninitialized -fomit-frame-pointer  -fno-stack-protector -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -D__KERNEL__ -I/home/tobi/RaLink_driver/UTIL/include -Wall -O2 -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fomit-frame-pointer -o -DMODULE -mlong-calls -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(rt_linux)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(rtutil3572sta)" -c -o /home/tobi/RaLink_driver/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/.tmp_rt_linux.o /home/tobi/RaLink_driver/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c
cc1: error: /home/tobi/RaLink_driver/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/.tmp_rt_linux.d: No such file or directory
distcc[29414] ERROR: compile (null) on localhost failed
make[8]: *** [/home/tobi/RaLink_driver/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.o] Error 1
make[7]: *** [_module_/home/tobi/RaLink_driver/UTIL/os/linux] Error 2
```

Without distcc log is the same but without error

```
cc1: error: /home/tobi/RaLink_driver/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/.tmp_rt_linux.d: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone say what is wrong?

Comment: You could check if distcc calls the correct complier (gcc vs. mipsel-linux-gcc).

Comment: I dont fully understand you... i have to use mipsel-linux-gcc. Compilation of all other drivers is fine. I have troubles only with RaLink.

Answer (score 0):

gcc's [`-Wp,MD`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-MD-614) does not take an argument. I think you might want to change this line:

```
-Wp,-MD,/home/tobi/RaLink_driver/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/.rt_linux.o.d
```

to use [-Wp,MF](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#dashMF):

```
-Wp,MD -Wp,MF /home/tobi/RaLink_driver/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/.rt_linux.o.d
```